# Can we work with MDB and EJB's in Quarkus

Tags: jms, ejb, quarkus, activemq-artemis, message-driven-bean

I tried looking into whether we can use MDBs and EJBs with the Quarkus framework, but I couldn't find any resources on Quarkus documentation. Can you please explain whether it is possible?

Basically, I want to consume the message from the Artemis brokers using Quarkus, but is it possible to do it using MDW and EJB?

Comment: Quarkus does not support EJBs (or MDBs for that matter). You can use https://quarkus.io/guides/amqp or https://quarkus.io/guides/jms.

Comment: If you want to use EJBs and MDB and work on something lightweight I'd suggest checking out [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io). Quarkus is mostly for REST apps, or has its own integration modules but no EJBs nor MDBs.

Comment: Thank you Ladicek and Gas for your comments i will check the mentioned resources , a small doubt , why does quarkus does not support this EJB's and MDB's ? as it is quite similar to spring framework

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus does not support EJB (including MDB). The EJB specification has a lot of complexity and historical baggage that's probably not obvious to the average application developer. It wouldn't make sense for Quarkus to support it. If you want to use EJB then you should use Java EE. If you want to use Quarkus then you can consume JMS messages with the facilities that it provides.